# $F=\frac{dp}{dt}$ or $F=ma$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass

The second law of Sir Isaac Newton or also known as the fundamental relation of dynamics :
$$\vec{F}=m\vec{a}$$ 
Which can be derived using the definition of the force :
$$\vec{F}=\frac{d\vec{p}}{dt}$$
But only if $m$ is treated as a constant. What if $m$ is not a constant? absolutely we're not having the same result. Then what we must apply $F=ma$ or $F=dp/dt$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In classical mechanics mass is always a constant. Matter is conserved (it gets a little more complicated in relativity and quantum mechanics but that need not concern us here). When dealing with a question involving "variable mass", for example rocket propulsion, one must divide the mass into the parts which are moving differently.  See e.g. [Rocket equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation). The force accelerating the rocket is $ma$, where $m$ is variable. It is NOT $ma + v\dot m$

Comment: This answer should be awarded 'correct answer'. +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

if m=const both are the same, if m ist not constant like in rockets you have to use change of  impulse .